# how get data from installed facebook app on iphone?

Tags: iphone, facebook, sharekit, fb-graph

I want to get data like user information from installed Facebook app (I dont need to login screen again on app, like it does in FBGraph or ShareKit) on iPhone. I should be able to get data directly from installed Facebook app (if its installed).  How should I do that ?

Its pretty urgent for me. Anybody have any idea ?

Comment: Use Social.framework and get the user's permission to access their on–device facebook account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not get data from installed app due to privacy concerns. Do google about **Sandbox**.

Answer (score 0):

You can get user information using the following lines of code. Please check the documentation [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.1/class/FBRequest).

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
    FBRequest *me = [FBRequest requestForMe];
    [me startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                      NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *my,
                                      NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Firstname - %@", my.first_name);
    }];
}
```

Comment: I guess he is talking about installed app, No ?

Comment: Oh Sorry, my mistake. :-)